# WinSCP Returns 'Access Denied' From WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to connect to an SFTP server using WinSCP. When I do it in a Win forms app it connects no problem. However, using exactly the same code in a WCF service returns 'Access Denied'.

I have checked repeatedly that Protocol, HostName, UserName, Password, SshPrivateKeyPassphrase and SshHostKeyFingerprint are the same in both apps, and that SshPrivateKeyPath points to a file that the DefaultAppPool can access.

Is there something else that I am missing to get this to work in WCF.

Edit: I should have mentioned that is the call to session.Open(sessionOptions); that returns 'Access Denied'.

Comment: Show us a WinSCP session log file both for the WCF and WinForms.

Comment: Where can I find these log files?

Comment: Set `Session.SessionLogPath`.